# Huawei HG532d Channel 14

Tags: router

"Channel 14" 2473GHz - 2495GHz
Is There A Way To Enable My Router To Broadcast On Channel 14? or Trick Channel 13 into broadcasting 2473GHz - 2495GHz?

Comment: This may have a legal consequence, depending on local radio emissions regulations.

Comment: This entirely depends if your router has already made it impossible for even third-party firmware to use this channel.  I am more inclined to assume, Huawei being a major manufacture, has already closed this loophole.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, the channels are defined in the PHY of the radio and can't be changed by config.

Answer (score 1):

Channel 14 is Japan-only and I seem to recall that it has such strict band-edge power regulations that it was only good for 802.11b, and even in Japan they don't bother with it anymore.

If your router lets you set which country (regulatory domain) you're in, set it to Japan and see if channel 14 becomes available.